# HTML CSS Invisible Button

Tags: html, css, button, invisible

Hello I am trying to make an invisible button (still functional and clickable), because my buttons styles are embedded in the background and I don't want to slice them, and do it all from beginning.

So I just want to make a button, put it on the part of the background where the button should be and make it invisible so the background button image can be seen and clicked.

Any suggestions? Thank you very much!

Comment: CSS -> background:transparent ?

Comment: you could use an image map and javascript event handlers, but I have to question why you don't want to do this using a more semantic markup

Comment: can you provide some code you tried?

Comment: You want to just use the background to style your buttons? Really?

Comment: really, not the best of plans.

Comment: i have tried with css opacity: 0;

Comment: i know its not the best of plans, im just fooling around with all kinds of settings. learning in an odd way

Answer (score 39, accepted):

you must use the following properties for a `button` element to make it transparent.

## Transparent Button With No Text

```
button {

    background: transparent;
    border: none !important;
    font-size:0;
}
```

## Transparent Button With Visible Text

```
button {

    background: transparent;
    border: none !important;
}​
```

and use absolute `position` to position the element.

## For Example

you have the button element under a div. Use `position` : relative on div and `position`: absolute on the button to position it within the div.

here is a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5k68J/1/)

here is an updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VXBVK/) that displays only text from the button.

Comment: thanks, is there anyway to hide everything (while its clickable) but still display the button text only?

Comment: if you want to see the button text, just remove the `font-size:0;` from the above code. see updated answer.

Answer (score 12):

You can use CSS to hide the button.

```
button {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

If your `<button>` is just a clickable area on the image, why bother make it a button? You can use [`<map>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/map) element instead.

Answer (score 8):

```
button {
    background:transparent;
    border:none;
    outline:none;
    display:block;
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Give the height and width with respect to the image in the background.This removes the borders and color of a button.You might also need to position it absolute so you can correctly place it where you need.I cant help you further without posting you code

To make it truly invisible you have to set ***outline:none;*** otherwise there would be a blue outline in some browsers and you have to set ***display:block*** if you need to click it and set dimensions to it

Comment: thanks, is there anyway to hide everything (while its clickable) but still display the button text only?

Comment: To make the button completely invisible, I set "cursor" to be default, so even when hovering over the button's location, the cursor will never change to a hand. This was exactly the direction I needed - thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**HTML**

```
<input type="button">
```

**CSS**

```
input[type=button]{
 background:transparent;
 border:0;
}
```

Comment: thanks, is there anyway to hide everything (while its clickable) but still display the button text only?

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS `background:transparent;` to your button/div.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S8fZC/1/)