# How to make a transparent HTML button?

Tags: html, css

I am using dreamweaver to create a website and I thought of just using Photoshop to create backgrounds. I decided to do so only because in case I'd choose to change the button name easily by just editing the codes, I could just refer to the code. If I would construct buttons using Photoshop, I wouldn't be able to edit the Texts in those buttons or in any element easily.

So my question is simple, How do I create a button that has a simple inline style making it transparent leaving the value of the button still visible.

```
.button {     
    background-color: Transparent;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    border: none;
    cursor:pointer;
    overflow: hidden;        
}
```

It still leaves a border shade after your click it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML CSS Invisible Button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13990629/html-css-invisible-button)

Answer (score 316, accepted):

To get rid of the outline when clicking, add `outline:none`

**[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/GQevc/)**

```
button {
    background-color: transparent;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline: none;
}
```

```css
button {
    background-color: transparent;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<button>button</button>
```

Comment: This is actually good enough. I've already tried the image way and it did as exactly needed. Thank you so much, Mr. Hayes!

Comment: It works 100% after include `-webkit-box-shadow: none; -moz-box-shadow: none;` in the code

Comment: You can optimize it changing `background-color: Transparent; background-repeat:no-repeat;` to `background: Transparent no-repeat;`

Comment: missing `outline: none;` gets me every time

Comment: For me, I had to apply the property "cursor: pointer" to button:hover. With solely button it did not work.

Answer (score 9):

The solution is pretty easy actually:

```
<button style="border:1px solid black; background-color: transparent;">Test</button>
```

This is doing an inline style. You're defining the border to be 1px, solid line, and black in color. The background color is then set to transparent.

---

**UPDATE**

Seems like your ACTUAL question is how do you prevent the border after clicking on it. That can be resolved with a CSS pseudo selector: `:active`.

```
button {
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    outline: none;
}
button:focus {
    border: none;
}
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/enigmarm/23gjC/1/)

Comment: Still leaves a border shade after you have clicked it. Thank you for your input!

Comment: So, your actual question is very different from the original one that I responded to. You already know how to use CSS to make the button transparent. After it has been clicked on, it's leaving a border you don't want. Is that accurate?

Comment: Yes, I am terribly sorry if my question was misleading.

Answer (score 2):

Make a div and use your image ( png with transparent background ) as the background of the div, then you can apply any text within that div to hover over the button. Something like this:

```
<div class="button" onclick="yourbuttonclickfunction();" >
Your Button Label Here
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.button {
height:20px;
width:40px;
background: url("yourimage.png");
}
```

Comment: If you want to keep your html semantic and accessible, it's best to use the button tag and remove background, etc.. using css. However, this is fine, especially in a situation where accessibility is not an issue like a native app that uses html5 and CSS for layout, here is an example:
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/10/17/best-of-both-worlds-mixing-html5-native-code/

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="button_style">
This is your button value
</div>

.button_style{   
background-color: Transparent;
border: none;             /* Your can add different style/properties of button Here*/
cursor:pointer;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting its background image to none also works:

```
button {
    background-image: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**add the icon top button like this **

```css
#copy_btn{
 align-items: center;
 position: absolute;
 width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
     background-color: Transparent;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    border: none;
    cursor:pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline:none;
}
.icon_copy{
 position: absolute;
 padding: 0px;
 top:0;
 left: 0;
width: 25px;
  height: 35px;
  
}
```

```html
<button id="copy_btn">

                        <img class="icon_copy" src="./assest/copy.svg" alt="Copy Text">
</button>
```