# Make button invisible but img on top of it visible

Tags: html, css

so I have some pseudo code that looks like this

```
<button><img src="name.png"/></button>
```

I want the button to be invisible but clickable, and the image to be visible.  I tried changing the opacity of the button but it also changes the opacity of the image.  Hiding the button behind the image looks ugly.  Any way to accomplish what I want?

Comment: Your css code.?

Comment: Why not make the image a link?

Comment: [check it out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13990629/html-css-invisible-button)

Comment: Are you sure you need a button ? Why not just handling/catching an "onClick" event on the image with a CSS "#myImg { cursor: pointer; }" rule ?